# Angular file-saver unknown provider

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bower

I installed angular-file-saver with

```
bower install angular-file-saver
```

Then I added the dependancy in my bower.json file :

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "^1.4.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.2.0",
    "file-saver.js": "^1.20150507.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": "^1.4.0"
  },
  "appPath": "app",
  "moduleName": "app",
  "overrides": {
    "bootstrap": {
      "main": [
        "less/bootstrap.less",
        "dist/css/bootstrap.css",
        "dist/js/bootstrap.js"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The bower.json from file-saver.js is

```
{
  "name": "file-saver.js",
  "main": "FileSaver.js",
  "version": "1.20150507.2",
  "homepage": "https://github.com/Teleborder/FileSaver.js",
  "authors": [
    "Eli Grey (http://eligrey.com)"
  ],
  "description": "A saveAs() FileSaver implementation",
  "keywords": [
    "File",
    "FileSaver",
    "saveAs"
  ],
  "license": "LICENSE.md",
  "ignore": [
    "**/.*",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "test",
    "tests",
    "demo",
    "FileSaver.min.js"
  ]
}
```

Then I imported it in my controller :

```
controller('MainCtrl', ['$http', 'file-saver.js', function ($http, fs) {
```

But I get the error :

```
Error: "[$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: file-saver.jsProvider <- file-saver.js <- MainCtrl
https://errors.angularjs.org/1.7.8/$injector/unpr?p0=file-saver.jsProvider%20%3C-%20file-saver.js%20%3C-%20MainCtrl"
```

I tried other names like file-saver, FileSaver, FileSaver.js but nothing works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation says that you need to import the `ngFileSaver` module in your module and then inject `FileSaver` in your component. Here's the example provided:

```
angular
  .module('fileSaverExample', ['ngFileSaver'])
  .controller('ExampleCtrl', ['FileSaver', 'Blob', ExampleCtrl]);
```

After that, you can invoke `FileSaver.saveAs` method.

Comment: Now I have [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ngFileSaver due to:
[$injector:nomod] Module 'ngFileSaver' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Comment: have you added the filesaver module js file to your index.html file ? or How are you using bower to inject dependencies ?

Comment: Bower automatically added "<script src="bower_components/file-saver.js/FileSaver.js"></script>" to my index.html file.

Comment: Oh your bower.json file contains `file-saver.js` while you installed `angular-file-saver`. Replace that and it should work

Comment: I didn't even see there was two folder I'm so dumb. Thanks so much.

Comment: You're welcome. Prefer using the `--save` option when you install dependencies with bower/npm.